# Is there a way to Customize parameter width in Report Builder Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, reportbuilder

I'm currently building a report in Report Builder Power Bi, and I want to adjust the width of the parameter window. Is there a way to do this?

I saw there's a way for columns in tablix, in the properties windows. But I do not see a visible way to do this for the parameters.

Thank you!

I'm expecting the parameter window (results window) to increase in width based on my custom input.